# Value becomes undefined after $digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Angular JS 1.4.7 + Typescript;
This is a then(), called inside controller.

Before $digest this code prints the actual object value (selectedCity object).
After $digest this code prints `undefined`. But why?

```
  .then((response:any) => {
    console.log("city " + stringify(response));

    $timeout(() => {
      this.selectedCity = response;
      console.log("before digest: " + stringify(this.selectedCity));
      $scope.$digest();
      console.log("after digest: " + stringify(this.selectedCity));
    });

    return response;
  });
```

Comment: Is `selectedCity` being bound as a model in your HTML? Also calling `$digest()` manually inside angular-controller code (`$timeout`) is _generally_ not good practice

Comment: This should have given you "$digest already in progress" error. Why are you even doing this?

Comment: @Rhumborl yes, it had notion like `ng-model="ctrl.selectedCity"`.
It seems like I have found how to workaround this behavior, because it was a directive bug (maybe feature). Directive erased the value on certain conditions.

Comment: Facing exactllly the same condition.. The http call in an isolated directive triggers a digest and finally my object turns undefined. Did u find a work around. Can someone suggest something. ???

Answer (score 0):

> After $digest this code prints undefined. But why

Because `$digest` does scope binding propogation. E.g. if you take `foo` into a directive with an isolate scope and the directive modifies it, the change will not probably unless there is a `$digest` active.

Comment: Care to explain a bit more. How could I make the changes permanent in the original object.